# Test if the object was modified correctly within the function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Let's supose that I have a javascript function that behaves like that:

```js
    function foo() {
        /* unnecessary code...*/
        const sendObjSomewhere = (param) => {/* anom function implementation */}
        return {
            async bar(obj) {
                try {
                    obj.name = obj.name.replace(/\w/g, '');
                    await sendObjSomewhere(obj);
                } catch () {
                     console.error('you messed up');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to show only the important part -- the objName variable and the function. My goal is to test if the obj.name is formated properly.

I've tried to use some libs but, unfortunately, I'm only allowed to use mocha and node native assertions (even more unfortunately, not allowed to extend mocha with other libs). How can I intercept `await sendObjSomewhere(obj);` and see how the params are being sent? Any other ways to test it are very welcome.

I'm using mocha 9.1.3 and node 16

Comment: `sendObjSomewhere` is a local variable to that function, there's no way to interact with it from tests at all. You might be able to monkeypatch some dependency that it has to determine whatit's doing, but trying to test "sendObjSomewhere" is the wrong approach imo. That's not part of that function's public contract, just an implementation detail.

Comment: use sinonJS and stub `sendObjSomewhere `

Comment: @bmz1 do you think isn't possible/simple to test using only mocha or node assertion?

Comment: No, you have to stub the function to see what params it is receiving. But sinon works well with mocha

Comment: @collinD Thanks for your help! What about testing if the obj.name is being formated properly? There is a way to grab the object to check it's values even if it is not returned?

Comment: @bmz1 how would you use sinon to stub a function you have no reference to? The test code can't "see" `sendObjSomewhere`